# "method requires pointer receiver" in Go Programming Language

Tags: go

I just saw a presentation of the Go programming language and thought I'd try to write a few lines. Everything worked fine until I tried to use an interface in this situation. How do I solve this?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type entity float32

func (e *entity) inc() {
    *e++
}

type incer interface {
    inc()
}

func doSomething(i incer) {
    i.inc()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")

    var e entity = 3
    e.inc()
    doSomething(e)
    fmt.Println(e)
}
```

I get the compiler error:

```
prog.go:24: cannot use e (type entity) as type incer in function argument:
entity does not implement incer (inc method requires pointer receiver)
```

I want to use a pointer so that the inc() will affect the enity outside the function. What is the syntax I should use?

/Ricky

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think there is some confusion here. `inc` is a method of the type `*entity`, and not of the type `entity` (while you can call methods on values directly on pointers; you cannot generally call methods on pointers directly on values). What you may be confused about is why you could call `e.inc()`, instead of having to do `(&e).inc()`. This is a little-known special case documented at the bottom of the [Calls](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Calls) section in the language specification, that says if `x` is addressable, and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, then `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`. This applies to this case because `e` is a variable, so it is addressable; but other expressions may not be addressable. I would recommend that you not use this shortcut, however, as it causes confusion; it makes you think that `e` conforms to the interface `inter`, while it does not.

Comment: @Ricky, to clear things up a bit more: actual arguments are always passed to methods by value, so for "accessor" methods the compiler has no troubles converting e.foo() to (&e).foo() but "mutator" methods must obviously change the real value, not their local method copy and hence values of non-reference types have to be passed to such methods using pointers, and the compiler cannot perform the trick being discussed. See "Should I define methods on values or pointers" in http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html

Comment: newacct: great explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Change it to: doSomething(&e). func (e *entity) inc() satisfies incer interface only for *entity type. There is no inc() for just entity type and that's what's you're passing to doSomething().