# In "A Go Tour", how do I modify the interface to require a method on a pointer?

Tags: go

In ["A Go Tour" on Interfaces](http://tour.golang.org/methods/4) we have this interface:

```
type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}
```

It is explained that this type, Vertex, does not satisfy the above Abser:

```
type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}
```

How do I modify the Abser interface so that Vertex satisfies it?

(It's okay if it no longer satisfies MyFloat in the full example.)

Before I posted this question I spent some hours searching and head scratching but after posting I found another SO question which covers similar material and may be of help to other neophytes:

["method requires pointer receiver” in Go Programming Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438323/method-requires-pointer-receiver-in-go-programming-language)

Comment: You cannot as `type Vertex` does not have any methods at all (only `*Vertex` has methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're slightly confused about what is implementing what. In this case, `*Vertex` is implementing `Abser` and not `Vertex` to make it so `Vertex` does as well, you have to change the receiving type on your implementation of `Abs` so that it's not a pointer;

```
func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
} // Vertex implementing Abser here
```

So the way you're phrasing the question is a bit misleading. The interface requires no change and should receive none. Just fyi, you can have both `*Vertex` and `Vertex` implement the interface by using the method I put above as well as the one you already have.

This is a point that often trips people up in Go. When you declare `func (t SomeType)` you're specifying the receiving type, if this is a pointer like `(t *SomeType)` then the thing implementing the interface is not `SomeType` but rather `*SomeType`. This differs a little from other languages where the method is implemented by the class and it doesn't matter if you're working with a reference or a value. In Go, the class doesn't implement the method, you specify the 'receiving type' - the thing that the method can be called on - that first argument actually gets pushed on the stack and used the same as an argument passed into a method, the distinction is only relevant for compilation (interface fulfillment really is the only reason to have the feature afaik). So, to summarize, if you want `Vertex` to implement the `Abser` interface which features a single method `Abs() float64` then you need to define the function as `func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 { ... }`.

Just for the sake of having clear readable code I recommend not having the interface defined for both pointers and values... You can work around that using the address of or dereference operator.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, although "slightly confused" is a bit of an understatement; I'm feeling particularly thick at the moment.

Comment: @DavidSmith how can I help clear up that confusion? Think of it this way, the implementing type is what's in the parenthesis to the left of the functions name. `AnyType` and `*AnyType` are not the same type. Whichever you use will be the one that implements the interface. If you're not familiar with the distinction between those I'd recommend reading a bit about pointers and value vs reference types. Most of the concepts are relevant in many systems languages (C, C++, C# to name a few).

Comment: You're very patient - I understand how I could change Abs to match the interface but the question that came to mind is, how to do the reverse; change the interface so the present Vertex satisfies it. I guess that I don't have any experience with using interfaces so from reading your answer, perhaps it is just a nonsense; you would never define an interface that requires a type to have a function that only acts on a pointer?

Comment: @DavidSmith to that last question, yes. What you're alluding to isn't possible and doesn't make a lot of sense. In Go, the pointer is a distinctly different type than the value version. If you want to make it so all that's required to fulfill the interface is a function pointer, you probably want to use embedding. I can elaborate on that if it's what you want. But to give more context, this is basically like having a function pointer on a struct in C. For a type to implement an interface, it must match the function definition, afaik an interface could not consist of a function pointer.